# How does move-staling work with bury-throws?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

As in past games, Smash Ultimate [stales your moves the more you use them](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Stale-move_negation). This also applies to most throws. The more a certain throw is used, the shorter the distance the opponent will be thrown.

However, Smash Ultimate has introduced a new type of throw: a bury-throw. This will cause the opponent to become buried when thrown. For example, King K. Rool and R.O.B.'s down throws will do this:

Since there's no actual trajectory to shorten when thrown, how does move-staling work with bury-throws? Does the bury time lessen as the throw stales? Or does staling not affect the throw at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason normal throws don't send opponents as far after staling is because staling actually lowers the damage dealt rather than change the formula on how far an opponent is sent.   The knockback formula can be looked at [here](https://www.ssbwiki.com/knockback) showing that the percentage a move deals helps determine it's knockback distance.  So staling on a bury throw will just make it easier (very slightly) to break out since getting out of a bury is based on your percentage when [buried](https://www.ssbwiki.com/Buried).

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of the knockback formulas being based on percent dealt. However, I don't see the logic for you last sentence--I don't see the connection between damage dealt and bury time. You talk about how it should be slightly **easier** to get out of bury, but then you talk about the opponents percent instead of the damage dealt.

Comment: @scohe001 it is slightly easier to get out of a staled bury rather than a 'fresh' one because it will deal a bit less damage, escaping a bury is solely dependent on one's percentage when entering the bury.  So while it will only get harder to escape repeated buries, it is easier to escape than if they used other moves to reset stale counter on the bury attack.

Comment: Ahh you're saying since the throw itself will deal less damage, the opponent will be at lower percent and thus the bury will be shorter. So the bury itself doesn't stale, just the damage dealt from the throw. Got it!